# Java: How can i sort a list of Objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, collections, compareto

I have a little problem, i hope you could help me solve it.

I have a class called Entity which has several attributes, two of those attributes are the **id** and the **utility**:

```
public class Entity implements Comparable <Entity> {

  int id;
  int utility;

}
```

Then, i have several Entity objects inside an ArrayList, like this:

```
ArrayList<Entity> sorted_entities = new ArrayList<Entity>
//added entities
```

Now, i want to sort the list basing on UTILITY entities. I tried several soluctions like this one which i read here, using a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(sorted_entities, new Comparator<Entity>() {

public int compare(Entity a, Entity b) {
    return a.utility.compareTo(b.utility);
}

});
```

But on this line:

```
return a.utility.compareTo(b.utility);
```

I met the following error: **int cannot be dereferenced** and i have no idea how fix it. Can you guys help me solve this problem or give another solution? Thx.

Comment: Sorry i found several topics but i didn't see that one with the comparator problem.

Comment: I really wonder why you create a `Comparator`, when your `Entity` already implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the wrapper types:

```
return Integer.valueOf(a.utility).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b.utility));
```

You can actually omit the explicit convert of `b.utility` to `Integer`, because it will be autoboxed anyway.

Alternatively (an even better), you can also do:

```
return Integer.compare(a.utility, b.utility);
```

where no boxing will be involved.

Comment: Thank you, i used your second code and the error disappeared. But another little problem: Collections.sort(blabla, the code that i posted upside, modified ofc) doesen't order my list, it do nothing. I have to made a sort of call to order the list? Sorry for the idiot question

Comment: calling `Collections.sort()` with the proper argument should sort your list. No additional work is needed. Try to print the list after the sort and/or debug it.

Comment: Ok nothing, problem solved, that helped too much! Thank you kocko! ^^